# How do I consolidate type annotations for component props while type checking screen components using NavigationStackScreenComponent type annotation?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Given below is the example available in React Navigation documentation for Version 4.x

```
import { NavigationStackScreenComponent } from 'react-navigation-stack';

type Params = { userId: string };

type ScreenProps = { language: string };

const ProfileScreen: NavigationStackScreenComponent<
  Params,
  ScreenProps
> = props => {
  // ...
};

ProfileScreen.navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: 'Profile',
};
```

I am still a noob in the typescript world but trying to adapt it to my React Native Projects.
The problem I am having is that `NavigationStackScreenComponent` generic accepts types for navigation params and screenProps but there is no way (maybe there is but I couldn't find it!) for me to add type annotations for component props.

Comment: Good question. I still haven't been able to type my params. Not sure why this example fails.